# Type does not have a member names 'objectForKey' and use of unresolved identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using swift/parse to attempt to populate custom cell in the following table view controller. The pfquery code seems to be going fine, but when I attempt to use the the data to populate cell.something.text with what should be returned results, I receive errors indicating that type does not a have a member named 'objectForKey' and Use of unresolved identifiers.  The errors are specifically all occurring under the override func tableView(tableView..cellForRowAtIndexPath....

```
import UIKit

class TimeLineTableViewController: UITableViewController {





    var timelineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
        // Custom initialization
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }



    func loadData(){
        timelineData.removeAllObjects()
        //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: PFuser = PFUser.current)
        var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "event")
        //findTimelineData.whereKey(PFUser.self, equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.timelineData.addObject(object)
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                    let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                    self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")

            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return timelineData.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TimeLineTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TimeLineTableViewCell

        let event:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

        cell.eventLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.dateLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.minutesLabel.alpha = 0

        cell.eventLabel.text = Category.objectForKey("content") as String
        cell.minutesLabel.text = duration.objectForKey


        var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        cell.dateLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(category.createdAt)

        var findRecorder:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
        findRecorder.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: event.objectForKey(user).objectId)

        findRecorder.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if error == nil{
                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser


                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                    cell.eventLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.dateLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.minutesLabel.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }


        return cell
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Your code appears to be invalid with undefined `duration` and no parameter sent when trying to use `objectForKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using variables you didn't initialize anywhere in your code:

```
cell.minutesLabel.text = duration.objectForKey
                            ^
cell.dateLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(category.createdAt)
                                                      ^
```

You never initialize `duration` or `category` in your code. So you can't access it. You first need to initialize it.

Also I'm not sure but it looks like that you don't import the Parse framework (maybe you do but it's not in the code you've provided)

So you will need to import it first:

```
import Parse
```

Comment: Thanks for response and see your point. Im new at Xcode and using parse, can't really find in the parse the documentation on how to initiate a single variable that I assume would be a PFObject. Any suggestions on this what you would suggest the code would look like?

Comment: I have tried : var category = PFObject(className:"Event") -without success.